# Reinstall vs Update IPA Files

Tags: ios, version

What are the significant difference between reinstalling and updating IPA files?

Does it only matters between retaining user preferences?

Comment: If you delete the app and reinstall then the data will gone, they will have to allow permission again, install on top of the app will maintain the data, thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that survives a reinstall (I assume you mean deleting and then installing) is the app's keychain values. So all data and preferences are gone. When you delete an app, the app's sandbox is wiped.

With an update, nothing is lost except (possibly) temporary and cache. No data or preferences are lost with an update. The new app is installed and the old version's sandbox is copied to the new app.